How to find a web link present within a customized command
How to define a new command that applies a default web link, except when the web link is already included within the command?
Compiler is: lualatex-dev.exe (2024)
My MWE is below
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,pdfversion = 1.7}}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\gdef\tempdoi{}
\def\doi#1{\gdef\tempdoi{#1}}

\doi{0000-0000-0000}

\def\foundweblink#1{\href{\tempdoi#1}{#1}}

We prove affiliation affsource figure ligature Lemma using the hypergraph container method, introduced by Balogh, Morris and Samotij, and independently by Saxton and Thomason.

\foundweblink{Sample content without any web links} 

%%Not compiling this
%%\foundweblink{Sample content without any web links \protect\href{https://www.google.com}{google}}

Recently, Morris, Samotij and Saxton introduced a refinement of the container method that takes into account the asymmetry between edges and non-edges in a sparse member of a hereditary graph proper

Expected Output:

%%\foundweblink{Sample content with any web links \protect\href{https://www.google.com}{google}}

The link is only applicable to the word 'Google'; other text will be displayed normally.

Same as below too
 %%\foundweblink{Sample content with any web links \url{https://www.google.com}}

 %%\foundweblink{Sample content with email address shiseeee0410@163.com}
\end{document}


Please clarify your question. As stated, it's unclear what you're looking for

@mbert, Whenever I create a new command, I want to check if the (\hyperlink|\url|\href) command is available within that customized command.

Please clarify within the question itself. Also, with that explanation I'm afraid it's still unclear

@mbert, Whenever I create a new command, I want to check if the (\hyperlink, \url, or \href) command is used within it. For example, my command name is \foundweblink. Example 1: \foundweblink{Plain text only}. Example 2: \foundweblink{Plain text with \hyperlink{www.google.com}{Google}}. Example 2 content should be displayed in the PDF output (i.e only if a hyperlink is present within the command). Example 1 not need to display in the PDF view.

As I said in the previous comment, please add these clarifications to the question, not in the comments

You can do this with \tl_if_in:NnTF, though I suspect the implementation I've given is quite slow and can be improved substantially.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \l_murugan_tempdoi_str
\NewDocumentCommand \doi { m }
  {
    \str_gset:Nn \l_murugan_tempdoi_str { #1 }
  }
\bool_new:N \l_murugan_nolinks_bool
\tl_new:N \l_murugan_tmp_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \foundweblink { m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \bool_set_true:N \l_murugan_nolinks_bool
    \tl_set:Nn \l_murugan_tmp_tl { #1 }
    \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_murugan_tmp_tl { \url }
      { \bool_set_false:N \l_murugan_nolinks_bool }
      {
        \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_murugan_tmp_tl { \href }
          { \bool_set_false:N \l_murugan_nolinks_bool }
          {
            \tl_if_in:NnT \l_murugan_tmp_tl { \hyperlink }
              { \bool_set_false:N \l_murugan_nolinks_bool }
          }
      }
    \bool_if:NTF \l_murugan_nolinks_bool
      { \href{ \l_murugan_tempdoi_str }{ #1 } }
      { #1 }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\doi{0000-0000-0000}

\begin{document}

We prove affiliation affsource figure ligature Lemma using the hypergraph container method, introduced by Balogh, Morris and Samotij, and independently by Saxton and Thomason.

\foundweblink{Sample content without any web links}

Recently, Morris, Samotij and Saxton introduced a refinement of the container method that takes into account the asymmetry between edges and non-edges in a sparse member of a hereditary graph proper

Expected Output:

\foundweblink{Sample content with any web links \href{https://www.google.com}{google}}

The link is only applicable to the word 'Google'; other text will be displayed normally.

Same as below too
\foundweblink{Sample content with any web links \url{https://www.google.com}}

\end{document}


